# using bootstrap splitting the page to two vertical space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to split the page into two and I want to do it horizontally using bootstrap: The top 1/3 of the page and bottom part the rest. Once it split it bottom part I want to get 4 columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tornado Chat Demo</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("chat.css") }}" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="body">
          <div id="inbox">
            {% for message in messages %}
              {% module Template("message.html", message=message) %}
            {% end %}
          </div>
          <div id="input">
            <form action="/a/message/new" method="post" id="messageform">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="body" id="message" style="width:500px"></td>
                  <td style="padding-left:5px">
                    <input type="submit" value="{{ _("Post") }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
                    {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- chat textbox closer -->
    <div class="clearifx"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p> Can I see this </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          Column2
          <p> Can I see this </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p> Can I see this </p>
          Column3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p> Can I see this </p>
          Column4
        </div>
    </div>     
    </div><!-- container closer -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ static_url("chat.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

But the form/input shows up in the bottom. How can I make sure the input and its responses stays in the top potion of the page and bottom gets split to 4 equal columns using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

`col-md-4` should be `col-md-3`, for the form on top try a clearfix div ,add a class `clear-meniu` to the container with the css:
try:
css:

```
.clear-meniu {
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container clear-meniu">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="body">
            <div id="inbox">
              .....
            </div>
            <div id="input">
                <form action="/a/message/new" method="post" id="messageform">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input name="body" id="message" style="width:500px">
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left:5px">
                                <input type="submit" value="Post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="equest.path">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- chat textbox closer -->
    <div class="clearifx"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Column1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Column2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Column3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Column4</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle for example :https://jsfiddle.net/4147mk1t/

Comment: still bottom row is row that has the inbox :(

Comment: how should I include bootstrap? I used the instructions in this site http://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2013/06/09/bootstrap-3-the-new-grid-system-for-starters/

Comment: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: when I add a navbar the row with the columns disappear

Comment: please post  all the html and the css

Comment: just added all the html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything in bootstrap that you can use to accomplish this, but you can just set both divs to be positioned absolutely and set height to the first one 33.3333333%, and set top: 33.33333333% for the second div.